# how make a loop when the input in game is a string but if is an int continuous?

Tags: python

I want to make a loop when the input in game() is a string but if is an int continuous?

```
def game():
     num = int(input("num?: "))
     if num % 3 == 0:
        return "right"
     else:
        return "wrong"
```

Comment: your input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop in combination with the method `isnumeric()` that tells if the string is the representation of an `int`

```
def game():
    num = input("num?: ")
    while not num.isnumeric():
        num = input("num?: ")

    if int(num) % 3 == 0:
        return "right"
    else:
        return "wrong"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `while` loop to your code with `isnumeric()` function that tells you if it's an `int` or not:

```
def game():
    num = input("num?: ")
    while not num.isnumeric():
        num = input("That's not a number bro, enter a number: ")

    if int(num) % 3 == 0:
        return "right"
    else:
        return "wrong"
```

Now as long as the input is not a number, your function repeats while user enters a number so that it terminates the loop.